# What is the easiest way to open a popup window to send an email?

Tags: email, coldfusion, popup

What is the simplest way to open a pop-up window, sending it information from the current page, allow the user to fill out a couple of fields and send an email, and then return to the original window as soon as the email was sent - using Coldfusion?

Comment: Why use a popup? You can accomplish the same thing using a overlayed div on the current page making an Ajax call to the server to send the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a simple javascript Window.Open, passing the parameters in the url.

Maybe not the best way, but definitely simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ColdFusion 8 or higher then I will suggest you to use CFWINDOW which will be simply div and can load content through ajax or just pre populated div can be convert to cfwindow and use modal version so it will not let user to use main page content. Also on send of email you can close cfwindow using javascript.

If you are using lesser than 8 then same thing can be implement using Fancybox or lightbox as well.

Comment: The link is actually *in* a cfwindow. So I'd like to popup a little separate window with the options

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use native HTML, my best advice is better use modaldialog box. After that, passing parameter from modaldialog box and display at parent page.